# Panning with right analog stick in Skyrim (PC) with ps3 controller

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, controllers, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I can play Skyrim on my PC with my PS3 controller (plugging it in via USB, and using the MotionInJoy tool), But for some reason the right analog stick does not allow me to pan... What do i do to allow it to pan?

Comment: Does this work the same way as using a standard gamepad on a Pc to play Oblivion? because if it does, then I know how to do it, as I had the same problem then, but I'm not sure if they work the same way, which is why I havent posted an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You probably aren't emulating a Xbox controller with MotioninJoy, so the game won't recognize the axis input.

This image shows how to do it:
[image]